# Second button wont work in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/linus/Desktop/chromedriver')

browser.get('Website')

searchBar = browser.find_element_by_id('a')
searchBar.send_keys('123456789')

button = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
button.click()
```

I open up my website and there is an input field. I type in my name and then click verify. The website waits for a connection from my phone, but the connection times out after about 1 minute. When it times out there is a button that says try again.

My problem is when the connection times out i can not make the python script click on the try again button i always have to do it manually. Is there a solution for this.

Comment: I don't understand problem. Show in question (not in comment) real URL so we could see problem. If you get error message then show it in question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

# all your code above from below

searchBar = browser.find_element_by_id('a')
searchBar.send_keys('123456789')

## once it reaches this point

# wait 70 seconds to continue to script. its abit above your average delay
time.sleep(70)

try:
    # try and click the button the pops up and click it
    button = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
    button.click()
else:
    button = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
    button.click()
```

Not sure if this will work, but something on the lines of this...